# How can I group on the created_at field and return only the Date and hour

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I run the following in Rails:

```
coe = trackers.where(:trackable_type => "Mailing").count(:group => 'DATE(created_at)')
```

which returns a hash with the items nicely grouped.

However I want to group not by date only by date  but by the hour, but not the minutes or seconds.

How can I run this query so all the heavy lifting is done by Postgresql and not convert after I get the data set back?

---

My mistake I want to group by Date and Hour.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the date_trunc() function:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE

Answer (score 1):

> I want to group **not** by date but by the hour, but not the minutes or
>   seconds.

Bold emphasis mine.
So `date_trunc()`is probably not what you want, but [`EXTRACT` or `date_part()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
coe = trackers.where(:trackable_type => "Mailing").count(:group => 'EXTRACT (hour FROM created_at)')
```

Comment: This looks good. Is there a way I can group by date and hour?

Comment: @chell: Sure, use @Kevin's answer for that: `date_trunc('hour', created_at)`.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Your a rock star